# Android JNI application : logging from a shared object

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have built a JNI application on Android, and I have some code in a shared object. Unfortunately, my shared object is giving me errors and I want to check where exactly is the error occurring in it. I want to add log lines to do the same. However, if I do a log using __android_log_write(), it does not appear in the logcat. What other options do I have, or is there a way to make this happen? If this question has been answered already, please point me to the link. My search did not yield me relevant results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an auxiliary class to Log easily in native code. There is a macro for every kind of verbose type. This is the Log.h file:

```
#ifndef LOG_H_
#define LOG_H_

#include <android/log.h>

#define LOGD(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGV(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

#endif /* LOG_H_ */
```

Then you can include "Log.h" in your classes and use it this way:

```
LOGI("YourClassTag","let's print some stuff: %i, %s", 4, "I'm a string");
```